# Using Combobox to popluate listview with SQL tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, combobox

I'm trying to get a combo box to populate the tech's invoices in the listview but so far it's not working.

Here's my table in SQL server:

`Tech`

`Tech_Id (PK) | First | Last | Phone | Customer_Count | --------------+-------+------+-------+----------------+ 
1             | Tim   | Bo   |9384027|        7       | 
2             | Andy  | Wong |9374927|        8       | 
3             | Jack  | Help |2183847|        8       |`

`Invoices`

`Invoice_Id (PK) |  Job_Descr  |Job_Date | Total | Term | Customer_Id | Tech_Id | -----------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+---------+ 
1                |Changed Motor|11/3/2014|   $30 |  30  |   2         |    1    |
2                |Tune up      |4/15/2013|   $50 |  30  |   11        |    2    |
3                |Changed PS   |9/14/2014|  $100 |  30  |   8         |    1    |`

Here's my code in c#:

```
    public TechForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (First+' '+Last) AS Name FROM Tech Order By First", con);
        con.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Name"]);
        }

        con.Close();

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tech (First, Last, Phone) VALUES ('" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Invoices JOIN Tech ON Invoices.Tech_Id = Tech.Tech_Id WHERE Last='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ; ", con);


            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["Invoice_Id"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Job_Descr"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Job_Date"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Total"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Customer_Id"].ToString());

                    listView1.Items.Add(item);

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What framework are you using? Winforms, WPF?

Comment: C# forms.  I guess that's windorms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are making an incorrect comparison.

The combobox.text is set to `Tech.First + ' ' + Tech.Last`, but when you check it for the comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(), you compare it to `Tech.Last`. Change it to `WHERE First + ' ' + Last='" + comboBox1.Text + "'`. So, in summary you are setting the combobox item as 'John Doe', and then populating the invoice listview with records where Tech.Last is 'John Doe'.